# Wechat miniprogram detect slot component changed

Tags: observer-pattern, wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I need to know, if it is possible to detect that the content of the **slot** of a custom component has changed.

This is my component:

```
//my-component.wxml
<view class = "wrapper">
<! - more code ->
<slot> </slot>
</view>
```

So to use it I do:
`<my-component> {{userName}} </my-component>`

I need to detect every time value of variable "**userName**" changes. This is a much simpler example, because if it were the value of a variable it would create a property on the component and create an observer.

I have searched the net a lot and have not found anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Wechat-miniprogram have no obverse if you want change the data, you can use this.setData({userName:'xxx'}).

Otherwise,if you want to obverse the datachange in view.You can use origin component "input".And bind the "change" event of "input".

The method of development is supported from offical.

If you want to use vue/react to develop your miniprogram, you must select other technology stack or frame likes wepy/taro/uniapp.

Comment: Hello @taolu, apparently you didn't understand my question. The example that I put was very simple. What I really have is a list with `<view style = "position: abosule" wx: for = "..."> ... </view>`. As the list view is absolute it does not make the parent grow, so I need to capture every time the view adds an element or an event to the end of the `wx:for` to then capture the height that the view has taken and be able to recalculate the size what should the father have

Comment: Maybe it will work with "Object.defineProperty" to observe the data in slot.It's example. [link](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/s/wA7e84mz70wa)